# Is it possible to run a function() within an android application with adb shell?

Tags: android

I've written an android application with an addNotification() function in the main activity.

I'm wondering if it's possible to call this function from my pc using adb shell commands whilst the application is running?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No.

But you can use intent extras, or make another class file for that function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not impossible.

I know many helper apps on android just like 360 phone helper and wandoujia helper get this kind of features:After you install this helper apps on your phone,and connect your phone to computer,this apps will run autolly and give a message to user to notify them that their phone has been connected to computer.

In fact, your android device is an linux like system after you root it.If you're familiar with terminal in linux and OSX,there must be some apps that you cannot ignore.

[Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)